# Fibonacci and Prime numbers Python

Tags: python, math, primes, fibonacci

Let `F[n]` and `P[n]` be the `n`th Fibonacci and prime number respectively. There are some values of `n` for which `F[n] % P[n] = 0`.

Let the first `k` indices which satisfies this condition be `n_1 < n_2 < ... < n_k`.

I want to calculate the sum of the first `k` indices (i.e. `n_1 + ... + n_k`). The program is fine for `k = 2` but too slow for `k = 5` (as below).

Is there any way I can speed this up?

```
def primelist(n):
  prime = [True]*n
  for p in range(3,n,2):
    if p**2>n:
    break
  if prime[p]:
    for i in range(p*p,n,2*p):
      prime[i]=False
 return [2]+[p for p in range(3,n,2) if prime[p]]
l= primelist(100000)
l.insert(0,0)
fib = [0,1]
for i in range(2,len(l)):
fib.append(fib[i-1]+fib[i-2])

k=0
sum_=0
i=1
while i<len(l):
  if fib[i]%l[i]==0:
    k=k+1
    sum_=sum_+i
  if k==5:
    i=len(l)-1
  i=i+1
print sum_
```

Comment: So? what is the problem?

Comment: Use faster implementations? For instance http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Python and http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Prime_number_generation#Python

Comment: Problem is I want to minimize the time need to get result as much as possible.

Comment: 100000 top limit for primes is not enough. you need more than that. but it isn't that far off (definitely less than a million first primes) so you should be able to calculate this in a sensible period of time (sequence of Fibonacci numbers should be very fast and simple to calculate since you have a built-in bignum in Python) - but you shouldn't keep them all, you just need *two* at a time. the Fibonacci numbers quickly get huge, and keeping them all in an array will need a lot of memory. just have two variables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those series are calculation intensive, in other words it doesn't surprise me that it is taking so much time to calculate the values especially that python is an interpreted language, making it slower in these kinds of calculations. I would suggest you use the library `numpy` to do the calculations you need. It will make your calculations much faster.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should redefine your variables like;

```
i+=1
```

Not;

```
i=i+1
```

Second one, tuples process are faster than lists. So you could use tuples instead of lists if you are not going to change anything.

> Also in this statement;

```
for p in range(3,n,2):
    if p**2>n:
        break
```

You probably want to do if p bigger than square root of n.So you should change that line to;

```
for p in range (3,int(n**0.5+1),2):
```